# laravel include path to make migration

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I need to add migrations to separate folder other than default migrations folder.

Here's the project structure:

```
root_project_name 
   -- app
   -- bootstrap
   -- .
   -- .
   -- database
      -- dmf_migrations
      -- migrations
```

I tried the following commands from the root project path:

```
php artisan make:migration create_dmf_result_set_table --path=/dmf_migrations/
```

Also tried:

- dmf_migrations
- /database/dmf_migrations/
- database/dmf_migrations

I get this error:

```
In ClassLoader.php line 444:

include(C:\xampp\htdocs\comp-intel-app\source\cpi\vendor\composer/../../database/migrations/2020_05_21_082135_create_dmf_result_set_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file
  or directory
```

What's the correct path?

Comment: for path `database/dmf_migrations` it worked after I renamed migration file. Can anyone please explain me this how renaming worked?

Comment: What did you rename it to?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert `creates_dmf_result_set_table`

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of migration name. What's important is that the folder you are creating in already exists.

Comment: @Sachem yes the folder already exists.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` should solve your issue without renaming

Answer (score 2):

You need to create dmf_migrations folder in your project's root directory.

Then run it with:

```
php artisan make:migration create_dmf_result_set_table --path=dmf_migrations
```

If you prefer to have it in database/dmf_migrations, then create dmf_migrations subfolder in database and run:

```
php artisan make:migration create_dmf_result_set_table --path=database/dmf_migrations
```